# How to set an environment variable working on both bash and GUI?

Tags: catalina, environment-variables

Considering the current version of macOS being Catalina, I am looking for a way to set permanently an environment variable for both: bash and GUI applications.

I have searched online for a while, but all solutions found fail because:

1. Only applies to older version of macOS: environment.plist, /etc/launchd.config, etc.
2. Only applies to bash: .profile, .bashrc, etc..
3. Not permanent solutions: export PATH=..

How to set environment variables permanently for bash and GUI applications?

Comment: What GUI applications are you using? What environmental variables are you looking to set?

Comment: For QtCreator, I need to add /usr/local/bin to PATH and also add one of my own env variables where custom libraries are located.

Comment: Actually, I found difficult to understand why /usr/local/bin is not by default in the PATH of GUI applications.

Comment: What is happening with QtCreator that you believe that path isn't set correctly?  Also, how is `launchd` *not* applicable to current version of macOS?  `launchd` is not only current, it's central to macOS!  Where did you read this?  Please provide links.

Comment: using CMAKE `message()` I can print `$ENV{PATH}` which return `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` (missing /usr/local/bin). This make some tools inaccessible like `conan`.
When I run qtCreator from a terminal, all works perfectly, thus making clear GUI application have a different `PATH`.
To reword, I am not saying launchd is not actual, but that the solutions using `launchd.config` to set the `PATH` for GUI applications (as explained in few answers) does not work anymore on Catalina (Tested myself and also reported by other users).

Comment: I don't think that a "GUi-visible" is equivalent to a "both GUI and bash"... Some people need to read the questions ;-)